# Has anyone out there tried to stop gaining rep so as to not surpass 10k?

Tags: discussion, reputation, 10k-tools

I recently discovered, or possibly rediscovered, that all deleted items are "[forced-visible to all 10k users all the time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33122/deleting-comments-not-by-me-on-my-answer/33142#33142)."  I never considered rep gain to be something with a downside before, especially because there's no way to directly message a non-diamond 10k user to ask for something to be closed/edited/deleted/whatever.  At my current levels of rep gain, this isn't something I'll have to worry about for a few years at least, but it seems to me that it could be pretty annoying to have to see all the stuff that gets deleted.  So I'm curious: **have any users tried to keep their rep under 10k, or reached 10k and regretted it?**

(At first I thought about asking what we could do about this, but then I realized I should first find out whether people actually consider it a problem or not.)

Comment: If it were that much of a problem you could always go the bounty lottery option to get back below 10k (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42501/is-bounty-rep-dump-gaming-subtitle-pollyanna-lottery)

Comment: it's not a big deal - not a high percentage of stuff.  By the way, the free telerik stuff is worth any potential downside I suppose.

Comment: Well, looks like [some people are thinking about this over on the Mathematics site](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2239/can-10k-users-turn-off-the-visibility-of-deleted-posts).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Nah, you get used to it after a while.  Really, there's so much noise that *doesn't* get deleted, a few deleted posts don't really get in the way that much.

And being able to *vote to delete* more than makes up for the minor irritation of seeing a few deleted posts.

Comment: Indeed. On SO I actively worked to get there...on meta, not so much. Being *able* to see deleted stuff on SO means I can contribute to "Why was my stuff deleted?" questions.

Answer (score 16):

Yes, that's why I haven't broken 10K. I had forgotten the reason.

Answer (score 9):

You don't really come across that much noise, so there's no reason to be concerned. It's not like you enter a new tax bracket or anything :)

Comment: Really?  It was my understanding that SO rep was pegged one-to-one to the Internet Dollar.

Comment: Nah, the exchange rate has been creeping up lately. Y'know, bad economy and all that.

Answer (score 2):

If it's a big deal, AdBlock Plus can block this class: `stackoverflow.com##.answer.deleted-answer`. TamperMonkey and other custom stylesheet/javascript tools can do this too. I just hit 10k, and was searching for this very thing, and am surprised this answer hasn't been given.

This is a sample [TamperMonkey](https://tampermonkey.net) script.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         stackoverflow tampering
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  StackOverflow - hide #hot-network-questions and deleted stuff.
// @author       mattmc3
// @grant        none
// @require http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js
// @match https://*.stackoverflow.com
// @match https://*.stackexchange.com
// ==/UserScript==

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.answer.deleted-answer').hide();
  // hide other stuff too
  $('#hot-network-questions').hide();
});
```

Comment: I prefer uBlock, thank you. Same cosmetic filter in either case.

Comment: No conspiracy, no deleted answers here. Most people simply don't care seeing deleted stuff same way they don't care seeing bad stuff all over the internet.

Comment: Deleted posts are charming