# Notification for moderator tools went off too early

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, notifications

I have received the following, slightly premature, notification.

[image: moderator tools notification above 9,993 score]

I don't have the required score, nor do I have access to the moderator tools (so far as I can see) — just the notification.

Comment: Perhaps the early warning is designed to give me time to prepare?  Put my affairs in order, spend some time with my loved ones, clear my desk etc?

Comment: Perhaps you did reach 10K which triggered the fact that the notification should be displayed and then had a vote removed which took you down below the score again. This then *didn't* clear the flag.

Comment: Perhaps a reverse notification is required: We're sorry, you've lost the privilege – access to moderator tools (with a less cheerful color than orange of course)

Comment: Jeff recently said that not removing the banner is by design for cases like the one Chris suggested.

Comment: This took, what, 10 minutes to resolve itself?  You are aware that posting frivolous bug reports can get your moderator tool access rights revoked?

Comment: @Hans, perhaps it's all part of the OP's plan to not suffer the responsibility that comes with mod tools. I guess we can now answer [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49822/has-anyone-out-there-tried-to-stop-gaining-rep-so-as-to-not-surpass-10k) with "yes."

Comment: @Hans Just because a bug resolves itself quickly doesn't mean it's not a legitimate bug report. It may be minor, but it's still worth bringing to the attention of the SE team.

Answer (score 10):

As Chris said above in comments, it's probably just unlucky that the script caught your rep >= 10k and then a vote was removed in the time you were away from the site.

But at the same time, I don't understand why the system doesn't do a final check when the notification is due to be delivered. I would think it's easy enough to figure out if the message doesn't apply, and unflag the privilege so you can get the notification at the proper time. Maybe it's too expensive a process.

I suppose we could forget the database part and deliver a different message instead.

[image: Pssst. Hey everyone -- let's all downvote him back down to 0]

Comment: fhc should be red (explains lack of upvotes)

Answer (score 5):

You *did* have more than 10k reputation -- but your reputation decreased, because someone either unaccepted one of your answers, performed an undo of an upvote on one of your posts, etc, etc.

I don't think this is common enough to warrant a whole set of code to prevent it; every new line of code is a potential new bug.

Comment: Yep, I had the same thing happen to me -- I got the notification and noticed that the "Tools" menu option was now visible, but by the time I clicked on the "Tools" link to see what it contained, I got a "Page Doesn't Exist" error. Someone had retracted one of their votes, putting me back down to 9,996. Funny timing I guess.

Comment: @donut http://blog.stackoverflow.com/wp-content/uploads/charlie-brown-lucy-football.png

Comment: Lol. Yep, that about sums it up.