# New privilege notification shows before I get the new privilege

Tags: bug, privileges, notification-bar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Notification for moderator tools went off too early](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70875/notification-for-moderator-tools-went-off-too-early)

[image]

As you can see, I get the new privilege notification bar even though I haven't gotten the new privilege yet.

Comment: Have you received a downvote recently?

Comment: If i did than it doesn't show in my reputation graph, as far as I can see I've never reached the 2000 rep.

Comment: Did you down-vote an answer?

Comment: @kiamlaluno no, there doesn't seem to be any negative rep points that whole day.

Comment: The only plausible explanation (which doesn't involve a bug) I can find is that somebody who up-voted one of your posts has then removed the up-voted, or somebody who before accepted an answer you gave accepted another answer.

Comment: What you see in the [reputation page](http://stackoverflow.com/reputation)?

Comment: @ShadowWizard  2   8067660 (10)
 2   8067660 (10)
-- 2011-11-09 rep +20   = 1984 for that day

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is fairly common, we shipped you the notification when you reached 2,000 however do not remove notification from your queue if you happen to slip below it.

There should be a dupe somewhere