# I was notified that I could use chat; is that a bug?

Tags: bug, reputation, chat, privileges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Notification for moderator tools went off too early](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70875/notification-for-moderator-tools-went-off-too-early)

I just connected to Stack Overflow and discovered that I got the privilege to "talk in chat,"
according to my notifications.

I clicked and read the page about the chat, and learned on the right that I am only at 85% to get the privilege.

Is it a bug that I got that notification?

I think maybe I gained reputation while I was offline which got me the privilege, and then lost reputation before I got back.

Comment: I see you edited my question, but I think you got it wrong. What I mean to ask was : Why is the notification still there ? Shouldn't it be removed when I lost the privilege before even knowing that I got it ?

Comment: Ah. I apologize for getting it wrong, but in my defense, you never actually said that. I will re-edit. It'll make this question a duplicate, I think.

Comment: Thanks, sorry if it wasn't clear, and also sorry for the grammatical mistake.

Comment: No worries, it all worked out. Welcome to Meta! (I didn't see that you were new here until just now.)

Comment: Thank you. And you are right, this is a duplicate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All StackExchange privileges can be gained and then lost again as your reputation goes up and down. You only need 20 reputation to talk in chat; a single up or down vote can cause you to gain or lose this privilege -- perhaps multiple times in the same day!

At this very instant, your rep on StackOverflow is 17, so you do not have that privilege. I'm confident that you'll get it back soon!

Comment: Let's assume someone vote up and down a hundred time while I'm offline, would I get a hundred notifications ?

Comment: No, I believe you're notified only the first time you gain a privilege.

Comment: So there is a bug ! You shouldn't see it if you don't have it anymore, or the message should be different.

Comment: No, it's like a piece of mail. If you get an email saying "You just got a raise!" and then you go punch your boss in the face, so that you lose your job, that email is still going to be in your inbox. Same here.

Comment: héhé, in such a case I will probably get another email saying "You loose your job".